# I have error message in running pmf of thinkbayes package

Tags: python, python-2.7, bayesian

I am running this script from ThinkBayes:

```
from thinkbayes import Pmf

pmf = Pmf()
pmf.Set('Bowl 1', 0.5)
pmf.Set('Bowl 2', 0.5)

pmf.Mult('Bowl 1', 0.75)
pmf.Mult('Bowl 2', 0.5)

pmf.Normalize()

print pmf.Prob('Bowl 1')
```

and I always get the error message:

File "C:/Users/Liying/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 12
    print pmf.Prob('Bowl 1')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please help and thanks!

Comment: This code was written for Python 2, where the `print` function did not require parenthesis. Just change the `print pmf.Prob('Bowl 1')` to `print(pmf.Prob('Bowl 1'))`

Comment: Thanks Adriano! Yes, when I rerun the new script, there is another error about print in the package itself.